# Detailed calculation to obtain Feynman rules of Standard Model

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

I am looking for a note deriving all interaction terms in detail of the Standard Model (after spontaneous symmetry breaking)?

In short, I need a note/reference showing in details how all the terms [here](https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/the-deconstructed-standard-model-equation) are derived starting with spontaneous symmetry breaking.

It would be great if someone could post some links or pdf or personal calculations. (I searched a bit on Google but couldn't get it)

Comment: [This way](http://einstein-schrodinger.com/Standard_Model.pdf) of writing the Standard Model Lagrangian is better organized and easier to grasp.

Comment: If my memory is correct, Peskin & Shroeder do it.